# Expanding tuples into arguments

Tags: python, tuples, parameter-passing

Suppose I have a function like:

```
def myfun(a, b, c):
    return (a * 2, b + c, c + b)
```

Given a tuple `some_tuple = (1, "foo", "bar")`, how would I use `some_tuple` to call `myfun`? This should output the result `(2, "foobar", "barfoo")`.

I know could define `myfun` so that it accepts the tuple directly, but I want to call the existing `myfun`.

---

<sub>See also: [What do ** (double star/asterisk) and * (star/asterisk) mean in a function call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2921847) - the corresponding question for people who encounter the syntax and are confused by it.</sub>

Answer (score 984, accepted):

`myfun(*some_tuple)` does exactly what you request. The `*` operator simply unpacks the tuple (or any iterable) and passes them as the positional arguments to the function. Read more about [unpacking arguments](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#tut-unpacking-arguments).

Comment: The * operator simply unpacks the tuple and passes them as the positional arguments to the function. See more here: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#tut-unpacking-arguments

Comment: Note that the same syntax can be used for lists as well as tuples.

Comment: I've found that you can do the same with lists, (in fact, any iterable, including strings), not sure how their mutability affects things. That would be interesting to look into.

Answer (score 80):

Note that you can also expand part of argument list:

```
myfun(1, *("foo", "bar"))
```

Comment: It appears you can only do this if the expanded tuple is after the normally-provided arguments - the interpreter doesn't like it when I do this: `some_func(*tuple_of_stuff, another_argument)`

Comment: @Quackmatic Having the expanded tuple in any location seems to work fine in Python 3.5.1

Comment: @Quackmatic seconding @River, this works fine in Python 3.5.4: `def func(a,b,c,d): print(a,b,c,d)` with `args = ('fee', 'fi', 'fo'); func(*args, 'fum')`

Answer (score 16):

Take a look at [the Python tutorial](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/controlflow.html#more-on-defining-functions) section 4.7.3 and 4.7.4.
It talks about passing tuples as arguments.

I would also consider using named parameters (and passing a dictionary) instead of using a tuple and passing a sequence. I find the use of positional arguments to be a bad practice when the positions are not intuitive or there are multiple parameters.

Answer (score 8):

This is the functional programming method. It lifts the tuple expansion feature out of syntax sugar:

```
apply_tuple = lambda f, t: f(*t)
```

Redefine `apply_tuple` via [`curry`](http://toolz.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#toolz.functoolz.curry) to save a lot of `partial` calls in the long run:

```
from toolz import curry
apply_tuple = curry(apply_tuple)
```

Example usage:

```
from operator import add, eq
from toolz import thread_last

thread_last(
    [(1,2), (3,4)],
    (map, apply_tuple(add)),
    list,
    (eq, [3, 7])
)
# Prints 'True'
```

Comment: This is not helpful for a beginner. It uses third-party modules and does other confusing stuff...

Comment: gberger, `lambda f, t: f(*t)` does not use third-party modules and I am a Python beginner and this is helpful to me. This is a pure functional approach. If you don't use this style then this answer is not for you.

Comment: toolz is third-party, is what I meant

Comment: Not every answer has to be for a beginner

Comment: @gberger I'm here because I was curious about a functional approach. :D

Comment: For the example you gave, one can use `starmap` https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/itertools.html#itertools.starmap

Comment: This is a terrible answer

Comment: An alternative definition with currying done by hand: `apply_tuple = lambda f: lambda args: f(*args)`

Answer (score 6):

Similar to @Dominykas's answer, this is a decorator that converts multiargument-accepting functions into tuple-accepting functions:

```
apply_tuple = lambda f: lambda args: f(*args)
```

Example 1:

```
def add(a, b):
    return a + b

three = apply_tuple(add)((1, 2))
```

Example 2:

```
@apply_tuple
def add(a, b):
    return a + b

three = add((1, 2))
```

Comment: You can also just define : def add(some_tyuple: tuple) and then access with an index