# How can I explode a tuple so that it can be passed as a parameter list?

Tags: python, parameters, tuples, iterable-unpacking

Let's say I have a method definition like this:

```
def myMethod(a, b, c, d, e)
```

Then, I have a variable and a tuple like this:

```
myVariable = 1
myTuple = (2, 3, 4, 5)
```

Is there a way I can pass explode the tuple so that I can pass its members as parameters? Something like this (although I know this won't work as the entire tuple is considered the second parameter):

```
myMethod(myVariable, myTuple)
```

I'd like to avoid referencing each tuple member individually if possible...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Expanding tuples into arguments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1993727/expanding-tuples-into-arguments)

Answer (score 47, accepted):

You are looking for the [argument unpacking](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/controlflow.html#unpacking-argument-lists) operator `*`:

```
myMethod(myVariable, *myTuple)
```

Comment: Nice, thanks! (I thought I had read about a method... still pretty new to Python though and wasn't sure how to search for it.)

Comment: @froadie: Right, there used to be -- actually, still is -- a function called `apply` which can serve the same purpose as the star and double-star operators. But `apply` is deprecated in favor of * and **. (See http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#apply)

Comment: Also works for iterables, in contradiction to the manual, which says it must be a sequence.

Answer (score 7):

From the [Python documentation](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/controlflow.html#unpacking-argument-lists):

> The reverse situation occurs when the
>   arguments are already in a list or
>   tuple but need to be unpacked for a
>   function call requiring separate
>   positional arguments. For instance,
>   the built-in range() function expects
>   separate start and stop arguments. If
>   they are not available separately,
>   write the function call with the
>   *-operator to unpack the arguments out of a list or tuple:

```
>>> range(3, 6)             # normal call with separate arguments
[3, 4, 5]
>>> args = [3, 6]
>>> range(*args)            # call with arguments unpacked from a list
[3, 4, 5]
```

> In the same fashion, dictionaries can
>   deliver keyword arguments with the
>   **-operator:

```
>>> def parrot(voltage, state='a stiff', action='voom'):
...     print "-- This parrot wouldn't", action,
...     print "if you put", voltage, "volts through it.",
...     print "E's", state, "!"
...
>>> d = {"voltage": "four million", "state": "bleedin' demised", "action": "VOOM"}
>>> parrot(**d)
-- This parrot wouldn't VOOM if you put four million volts through it. E's bleedin' demised !
```