# python array as list of parameters

Tags: python

I have an array that matches the parameters of a function:

```
        TmpfieldNames = []
        TmpfieldNames.append(Trademark.name)
        TmpfieldNames.append(Trademark.id)
        return func(Trademark.name, Trademark.id)
```

`func(Trademark.name.Trademark.id)` works, but `func(TmpfieldNames)` doesn't. How can I call the function without explicitly indexing into the array like `func(TmpfieldNames[0], TmpfieldNames[1])`?

Comment: That code doesn't make sense. You're just filling a list with `len(fieldNames)` copies of (references to) `Tademark.id`, then return the result of some function called with a single `Trademark.name` and `Trademark.id`. (Edit: Okay, that makes more sense)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I explode a tuple so that it can be passed as a parameter list?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3198218/how-can-i-explode-a-tuple-so-that-it-can-be-passed-as-a-parameter-list)

Answer (score 40):

With `*` you can unpack arguments from a `list` or `tuple` and `**` unpacks arguments from a `dict`.

```
>>> range(3, 6)             # normal call with separate arguments
[3, 4, 5]
>>> args = [3, 6]
>>> range(*args)            # call with arguments unpacked from a list
[3, 4, 5]
```

Example from the [documentation](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/controlflow.html#unpacking-argument-lists).

Answer (score 17):

I think what you are looking for is this:

```
def f(a, b):
    print a, b

arr = [1, 2]
f(*arr)
```

Comment: For the record, it's called argument unpacking and we already had it a dozen times on SO alone, not to mention all the Python tutorials...

Comment: Hard to find when you do know the name! Thanks for giving it out ;)

Comment: @Atais, Don't worry: guys like delnan assume that because they know how to find something, everyone else does too.

Answer (score 2):

What you are looking for is:

```
func(*TmpfieldNames)
```

But this isn't the typical use case for such a feature; I'm assuming you've created it for demonstration.