# Chained list comprehension in python

Tags: python, numpy, list-comprehension

```
this = rand(100,3,4)
for i in range(0,100):
    for j in range(0,3):
        for k in range(0,4):
            if rand()<0.5:
                this[i,j,k]=0
```

Where `rand` is `numpy.random.rand`

Can the above be written in chained list comprehension?

Aim: to assign value 0 to each term in "this" (3D matrix) with certain probability(0.5)

Comment: The output is not a list, so not sure why you are asking for a list comprehension? Are you asking is there a more pythonic way to refactor your nested for loops?

Comment: @Burhan : yes.
Can the same thing be done using a chained list comprehension? Without nested loops?

Comment: The result of a list comprehension is a _list_; your code is not generating a list (it is instead modifying the matrix) so not sure why you are looking for a list comprehension.

Comment: matrix can be thought of as lists in list, right? But I am more comfortable with your solution.

Just that comprehensions run faster. That's why I was into list comprehension. using `numpy.where` should be fast enough. :)

Comment: I should have been more explicit - a list comprehension expression evaluates to a _new list_; it is not designed for modifying lists in-place (you should avoid doing that anyway - its a great source of bugs). `numpy.where` would probably be faster if not equivalent to a comprehension - noting that you would be building a list, and then discarding it if you were to implement your loop as a comprehension.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems to me that you're better off using builtin numpy routines such as [`numpy.where`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html)...

```
>>> import numpy
>>> import numpy.random
>>> x = numpy.random.rand(100, 3, 4)
>>> mask = numpy.random.rand(*x.shape)
>>> result = numpy.where(mask < 0.5, 0, x)
```

Comment: Could you explain how does that `rand(*x.shape)` works? What does that * mean?

Comment: @AbhishekTripathi See [Expanding tuples into arguments](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1993727/expanding-tuples-into-arguments)