# TypeError when creating a MySQL table with parameters

Tags: python, mysql

Something is wrong either with this execute statement or with the list I'm passing into it.

I keep getting:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/Hardway/test_package/sqltest5.py", line 12, in <module>
    cur.execute(create_table, ('userid', 'age_of_account', 'number_of_friends', 'DA_MA', 'user_quality'))    
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/MySQL_python-1.2.4b4-py2.7-macosx-10.11-intel.egg/MySQLdb/cursors.py", line 184, in execute
    query = query % db.literal(args)
TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting
```

I've now tried everything (forcing tuples, 3 types of param variables in the string, etc) and could use some help. What am I missing?

```
import MySQLdb as MS
db1 = MS.connect(host="localhost", user="yosef",passwd="yosef", db ='test2')

cur = db1.cursor()

header = ('userid', 'age_of_account', 'number_of_friends', 'DA_MA', 'user_quality')
drop_table = "DROP TABLE IF EXISTS Users"
create_table = """Create table Users ({0} int, {1} int, {2} int, {3} float, {4} varchar(10))"""

try:
    cur.execute(drop_table)
    cur.execute(create_table, header,)    

    db1.commit()

except MS.Error, e:
    print "That failed"
    print e.args[0], e.args[1]
    db1.rollback()

finally:
    db1.close()
```

Comment: so this you already tried: create_table = "Create table Users ({0} int, {1} int, {2} int, {3} float, {4} varchar(10))".format('userid', 'age_of_account', 'number_of_friends', 'DA_MA', 'user_quality')?

Comment: Sure. As soon as I get to sit down in front of a computer and test them. Right now I've got a toddler I'm putting to bed. Doesn't make me any less grateful for the awesomeness of this community but it has prevented me from testing the code. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't pass column names as query parameters to `cursor.execute()`.  You'll have to use string [formatting](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.format) to interpolate them into the query:

```
create_table = ("CREATE TABLE Users ({} INT, {} INT, {} INT, {} FLOAT,"
                "{} VARCHAR(10))".format(*header))
cur.execute(create_table)
```

Of course, you need to be extremely careful that `header` doesn't contain user input.

Answer (score 1):

You can pass *values* in [MySQLCursor.execute](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-api-mysqlcursor-execute.html) but not the column names. So, use `str.format`:

```
create_table = "Create table Users ({0} int, {1} int, {2} int, {3} float, {4} varchar(10))".format(*header)
cur.execute(create_table)
```

Note that you need to use `*` to [expand the tuple](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1993732/2873538) when using with `str.format`.