# How can I unpack tuple when other variables are needed?

Tags: python, python-2.7, iterable-unpacking

According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1993727/3512538), I can call a function that takes N arguments with a tuple containing those arguments, with `f(*my_tuple)`.

Is there a way to combine unpacking and unpacked variables?

Something like:

```
def f(x,y,z):...
a = (1,2)
f(*a, 3)
```

Comment: How about `f(*(a + (3,)))`?

Comment: In Python 3.7 at least, `f(*a, 3)` is valid.

Comment: @ThomWiggers in 2.7 its not :-(

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The code you supplied (`f(*a, 3)`) is valid for python 3. For python 2, you can create a new tuple by adding in the extra values. Then unpack the new tuple.

For example if you had the following function `f`:

```
def f(x, y, z):
    return x*y - y*z

print(f(1,2,3))
#-4
```

Attempting your code results in an error in python 2:

```
a = (1,2)
print(f(*a,3))
#SyntaxError: only named arguments may follow *expression
```

So just make a new `tuple`:

```
new_a = a + (3,)
print(f(*new_a))
#-4
```

---

**Update**

I should also add another option is to pass in a *named* argument after the `*` expression (as stated in the `SyntaxError`):

```
print(f(*a, z=3))
#-4
```

Answer (score 2):

A little heavy, but you can use `functools.partial` to partially apply `f` to the arguments in `a` before calling the resulting callable on 3.

```
from functools import partial

partial(f, *a)(3)
```

This is more useful if you plan on making a lot of calls to `f` with the same two arguments from `a`, but with different 3rd arguments; for example:

```
a = (1,2)
g = partial(f, *a)
for k in some_list:
    g(k)  # Same as f(1,2,k)
```

Answer (score 0):

as @pault said - you can create a new tuple , and you can do another thing which is:

pass the `*a` as the **last** variable to a function, for example :

```
def f(x,y,z):...
a = (1,2)
f(3, *a)
```

worked for me in Python 2.7

Comment: The order of the arguments matter. `f(3, *a)` is **not** the same as `f(*(a + (3,)))`

Comment: Syntactically, it works, but in general positional arguments have to be passed in an expected order.

Comment: the order does matter so this will not help me, but its cool to see this works! UV

Comment: i know that for the OP the order matters - if you really want to call the function without new tuple , order in function declaration can be changed accordingly ,:)