# tuples as function arguments

Tags: python, python-3.x, tuples, python-internals

a `tuple` in python (in a code block) is defined by the commas; the parentheses are not mandatory (in the cases below). so these three are all equivalent:

```
a, b = 1, 2
a, b = (1, 2)
(a, b) = 1, 2
```

if i define a function

```
def f(a, b):
    print(a, b)
```

calling it this way will work:

```
f(2, 3)
```

this will not:

```
f((2, 3))
# TypeError: f() missing 1 required positional argument: 'b'
```

how does python treat tuples differently when they are function arguments? here the parentheses are necessary (i understand *why* this is the case and i am happy python works this way!).

my question is: how does python treat tuples differently when they are function arguments.

Comment: You might want to take a look at [this](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#more-on-defining-functions), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1993727/expanding-tuples-into-arguments), [PEP-3113](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3113/)

Answer (score 33, accepted):

For convenience, Python constructs a temporary tuple as needed for an assignment statement.  Thus, all three of your assignment statements are exactly the same once they reach data movement.

A function call is not an assignment statement; it's a reference mapping.  Therefore, the semantics are different.

If you want Python to unpack your tuple into two separate arguments, use the `*` operator:

```
f(*(2, 3))
```

Comment: *A function call is not an assignment statement; it's a reference mapping.* thanks for that! (i should really have learnt that by now!)

Comment: "Python constructs a temporary tuple" -- conceptually this is what Python does, but in reality it just pushes objects onto a stack and pops them off again. No tuple is ever created. Try seeing what [`dis.dis`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/dis.html) outputs for a function that executes `a, b = b, a`.

Answer (score 12):

**A tuple behaves like an immutable list.** The fact that you notate them with parentheses is perhaps confusing, but it's more or less a coincidence - a result of the fact that parentheses are used for grouping things together and reducing ambiguity otherwise.

When you call a function, you're not providing a tuple. You're providing arguments. A tuple *can be* an argument, but only one - it's just a variable of type `tuple`.

What you can do is *expand* a tuple (or a list) into a a series of arguments with this notation:

```
tup = (2, 3)
f(*tup)
# expand the tuple (2,3) into a series of arguments 2, 3
```

You can do that with dictionaries as well, except with `**` instead of `*`:

```
my_dict = {"arg1": 1, "arg2": 2}
f(arg1=my_dict["arg1"], arg2=my_dict["arg2"])
f(**my_dict)   # these are equivalent
```

---

On the other hand, functions can take arbitrary numbers of arguments (similar to how other languages do for `printf()` calls). For example:

```
def g(*args):
    print("I got this many arguments:", len(args))
```

Here, if you do `type(args)`, you get `tuple`, and if you do `type(*args)`, you get an error. This is because, in function headers, the `*` does the exact opposite: it packs the arguments that were given to the function into a single tuple, so that you can work with them. Consider the following:

```
g(2, 3)  # 2 arguments, both integers
g((2, 3)) # 1 argument, a tuple
g(*(2, 3)) # 2 arguments, both integers
```

In short,

- functions are built in such a way that they take an arbitrary number of arguments
- The `*` and `**` operators are able to *unpack* tuples/lists/dicts into arguments on one end, and *pack* them on the other end
- individual tuples/lists/dicts are otherwise just individual variables.

Comment: I feel this doesn' t really answer his question, he's asking why the 2, 3 in func(2, 3) isn't a tuple. It should be if the parens were that optional.

Comment: Because that's how the language is defined. A tuple is a datatype, just like any other type of variable. Functions take a sequence of arguments (of various types) - not just one argument that happens to hold the rest of the arguments. While it's true a number of functions (e.g. `threading` stuff) use tuples to specify what arguments to provide to functions, that's out of necessity (providing a set of args as a variable).

Answer (score 7):

The thing is that parens are used for several different things in Python -- for calling functions, for making tuples (it's not *just* the commas that matter, see the empty tuple `()`), for changing evaluation priority in expressions.

In cases where interpreting them is ambiguous (e.g. your example `f(2, 3)` could be either a function call with two arguments, or a function call with one argument that is a tuple) the language has to make a choice.

If the Python parser was implemented so that it parsed this as a tuple, it would be impossible to have functions with more than one argument. If the Python parser was implemented so that it parsed this as two arguments, it's impossible to pass a literal tuple without the parens.

Clearly the first is a much bigger limitation, so the second was chosen.

Another example is with tuples with *one* element -- is `(1+2)` an expression yielding the number 3, or a tuple with one element, 3? Here if it was the second, then it would be impossible to use parens for expressing priority in an expression (`(3+4)*5` vs `3+(4*5)`). So it was decided to require the comma after the first element for 1-element tuples (`(3,)`).