# pass the multiple return values from one function to another function as an argument

Tags: python-3.x, function, return, python-module

I have the below code,

```
def hello(start, end):
    perform some function
    for i in range(j):
        yield (some value)
    yield (some value)

def calc(start, end):
    start = "x"
    end = "y"
    for d in hello(start, end):
        perform some function       
        data = 123
        perform some function 
        data1 = 456
    return data, data1

def world(hello()):
    with open(r"C:\filepath\abc.json",'w') as file:
        json.dump(hello.data, file)
    
    with open(r"C:\filepath\abc.json") as file1:
        d = json.load(file1)
    return d
```

1. Now, I want to use return values(data & data1) from hello() function
   in world() function, also want to use return values from world()
   function in another function.
2. Also, the world() function will be imported as a module and should
   be used in function in another module.

How could I do that?

Answer (score 2):

1. You could use the `*` operator to unpack the return value. The following example works for me:

```
def func1():
    return 10, 's10'

def func2(code, codeString):
    print("code: ", code)
    return codeString
   

cs = func2(*func1())
print("Code string: ", cs)
```

Please see [tuples as function arguments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56498558/tuples-as-function-arguments) for more details.