# I have problem with last for loop. It shows me just last student in array, but it should be all 5

Tags: python, loops, for-loop

I have a problem with for loop. how can I solve it?

Here 3 arrays which I need to put in for loop and print by class:

```py
name = ["Scott", "Liz", "Sarah", "Mark", "Dan"]
address = ["21, old kent road", "13,Trafalgar Square", "45,KingsCross Road", "33,Russel square",
           "56,Lewisham Road"]
telephone = ["02075642222", "02078642123", "02084641111", "02085553234", "02076662123"]
students = []
```

here I loop and launch my class that print all students:

```py
for i in range(len(name),len(address),len(telephone)):
    stud1 = Studentdetails(name[i], address[i], telephone[I])
```

I have problem with last for loop. It shows me just last student in array, but it should be all 5.

Comment: You don't print anything in that loop.

Comment: `range(len(name),len(address),len(telephone))` does NOT work how you think it does. The first argument of `range` is the starting number of the range, the second argument is the ending number, and the third argument is the number of steps between each number in the range. This does NOT just loop through all 3 lists. You also have a capital `I` in `telephone[I]` when it should be `telephone[i]`, seemingly. You'll need to look up `range` and play around with it a bit to understand how it works, because you're using it incorrectly.

Comment: If you want to loop through all three lists, you could use `for n,a,t in zip(name,address,telephone):`

Comment: first you have to learn how to use `range(start, end, step)`. But really you need `zip()` instead of `range()`

Comment: Once you've figured out how to manage the outer loop you'll have to ask yourself what's happening with *stud1*. It will simply be overridden each iteration and will ultimately contain the last value that was assigned to it. You probably want to build a list. Have you considered how you should handle a situation where the element count of your three lists are not equal?

Comment: @Georgii Could you clarify what the `Studentdetails` function does? Does it print something?

Comment: @BenGrossmann I suspect that Studentdetails is a class. Just a wild guess

Answer (score 1):

Generally avoid using `range(len)` you almost always don't need it. Python `for` works like `for each`.

If your `studentdetails` takes the three arguments you can use zip to loop over multiple items and unpack it with *:

```
for student in zip(name, address, telephone):
    students.append(studentdetails(*student))
```

This is equivalent to:

```
for studentname, studentaddress, studenttel in zip(name, address, telephone):
    students.append(studentdetails(studentname, studentaddress, studenttel))
```

If you are going to be doing this for a larger set of data the fastest way to fill the `students` list with the results of `studentdetails()` would be to add a short generator which unpacks the `zip` and `yields` the `studentdetails()` for each set of details:

```
def createstudents(iter):
    for item in iter:
        yield studentdetails(*item)

students = list(createstudents(zip(name, address, telephone)))
```

This then reads like the sentence: *"students is the list of createstudents for each group of name, address, telephone)"*
and createstudents is *"for each item in the iterator: yield me the studentdetails object"*

For great insights in the pythonic way of doing this sort of thing check out the first 10 minutes of: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OSGv2VnC0go

Comment: You're not calling their `Studentdetails` function/constructor though. For all we know, that's what prints what they want. The issue here is that they're looping over an incorrect range.

Comment: Good catch - thanks @RandomDavis - updated to reflect that

Answer (score 1):

All your lists are length 5 (and I assume they will always be the same length), so there's no need to factor in all their different lengths. You just need the length of one of them in order to loop. The way you have it currently, you're doing `range(5, 5, 5)`, which is empty, because of the behavior of `range` given those arguments. Like I said in my comment, the first number is the starting number, the second number is the ending number, and the third number is the "step". For more info see: https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#func-range

So, your code should work fine if you do:

```py
for i in range(len(name)):
    stud1 = Studentdetails(name[i], address[i], telephone[i])
```

**There are more ways to make this more "Pythonic" but you can feel free to ignore everything below if it's too confusing:**

You can use the `zip` function to iterate through all 3 lists at once, with each item in the `zip` being a `tuple` of the 3 list items for that index. So, this would work just as well:

```py
for n, a, t in zip(name, address, telephone):
    stud1 = Studentdetails(n, a, t)
```

You could also [use the asterisk operator](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56498558/6273251) to automatically expand the tuple into a list of arguments to pass to `Studentdetails`:

```py
for s in zip(name, address, telephone):
    stud1 = Studentdetails(*s)
```

Comment: This would do it, but you need to decide what to do if the list length differs. However `zip` may be a better choice.

Comment: `zip` might look a little cleaner but I just wanted to provide the minimal amount of changes to allow this to work, so as to not introduce too much confusing, unnecessary new information, considering this is someone who's brand new to Python seemingly. And yes, if the lengths differ then that's another problem, but it does not appear to be relevant in this case. I would assume that for this homework assignment, the lengths probably will not differ.

Comment: @ctrl-alt-delor I did end up adding an example of `zip`, but just with a disclaimer.

Comment: No criticism of you answer ( up voted it). I manly wanted to agree with it, but with a ₛₘₐₗₗ caveat.

Comment: @ctrl-alt-delor no worries, no criticism interpreted.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that Studentdetails is a class so I'll emulate it here and show how a list of students could be constructed:

```
class Studentdetails:
    def __init__(self, name, address, telephone):
        self.name = name
        self.address = address
        self.telephone = telephone
    def __repr__(self):
        return f'Name={self.name}, Address={self.address}, Telephone={self.telephone}'

name = ["Scott", "Liz", "Sarah", "Mark", "Dan"]
address = ["21, old kent road", "13,Trafalgar Square", "45,KingsCross Road", "33,Russel square",
           "56,Lewisham Road"]
telephone = ["02075642222", "02078642123", "02084641111", "02085553234", "02076662123"]
students = []

assert len(name) == len(address) and len(address) == len(telephone)

for name_, address_, telephone_ in zip(name, address, telephone):
    students.append(Studentdetails(name_, address_, telephone_))

for student in students:
    print(student)
```

**Output:**

```
Name=Scott, Address=21, old kent road, Telephone=02075642222
Name=Liz, Address=13,Trafalgar Square, Telephone=02078642123
Name=Sarah, Address=45,KingsCross Road, Telephone=02084641111
Name=Mark, Address=33,Russel square, Telephone=02085553234
Name=Dan, Address=56,Lewisham Road, Telephone=02076662123
```

Comment: thank you, you are right, it is class. Now it works for me.

Answer (score 0):

```
class Studentdetails:
    def __init__(self, name, address, telephone, address2="London"):
        self.name = name
        self.address = address
        self.telephone = telephone
        self.city = address2

    def __repr__(self):
        return f'Name={self.name}, Address={self.address}, City={self.city}, Telephone={self.telephone}'


class Totalmarks():
    def __init__(self, total=0.0, average=0.0):
        self.totmarks = total
        self.average = average

    def total(self, total):
        self.markslist = total
        for i in range(5):
            self.totmarks = self.totmarks + self.markslist[i]
        return self.totmarks

    def Aver(self):
        self.average = self.totmarks / 5
        return self.average


class Teachercomments():
    def comments(self, average):
        self.average = average
        if self.average <= 30:
            print("Teacher Comments: ", "\n", "Needs to work hard and attend extra sessions to progress.")
        elif self.average >= 31 and self.average <= 50:
            print("Teacher Comments: ", "\n", "Needs to improve the quality of work produced to make a progression")
        elif self.average >= 51 and self.average <= 70:
            print("Teacher Comments: ", "\n",
                  "Making good progress but need to focus on certain topics to achieve high marks")
        elif self.average >= 71 and self.average <= 80:
            print("Teacher Comments: ", "\n", "Needs to be carefully")
        else:
            print("Teacher Comments: ", "\n", "Well done for making an excellent progress.")


def report():
    s = "*" * 65
    studtotal = Totalmarks()
    print(s, "\n", " " * 20, "Student Report", "\n", s)
    marks = []
    for i in range(5):
        smarks = int(input("please enter your mark"))
        marks.append(smarks)
    print(marks)
    sumtot = studtotal.total(marks)
    av = studtotal.Aver()
    print("Total marks:", sumtot)
    print("Average:", av)
    tcom = Teachercomments()
    tcom.comments(av)
report()



name = ["Scott", "Liz", "Sarah", "Mark", "Dan"]
address = ["21, old kent road", "13,Trafalgar Square", "45,KingsCross Road", "33,Russel square",
           "56,Lewisham Road"]
telephone = ["02075642222", "02078642123", "02084641111", "02085553234", "02076662123"]
students = []

assert len(name) == len(address) and len(address) == len(telephone)

for name_, address_, telephone_ in zip(name, address, telephone):
    students.append(Studentdetails(name_, address_, telephone_))

for student in students:
    print(student)
```

`Output`

```
***************************************************************** 
                      Student Report 
 *****************************************************************
please enter your mark1
please enter your mark2
please enter your mark3
please enter your mark4
please enter your mark45
[1, 2, 3, 4, 45]
Total marks: 55.0
Average: 11.0
Teacher Comments:  
 Needs to work hard and attend extra sessions to progress.
Name=Scott, Address=21, old kent road, City=London, Telephone=02075642222
Name=Liz, Address=13,Trafalgar Square, City=London, Telephone=02078642123
Name=Sarah, Address=45,KingsCross Road, City=London, Telephone=02084641111
Name=Mark, Address=33,Russel square, City=London, Telephone=02085553234
Name=Dan, Address=56,Lewisham Road, City=London, Telephone=02076662123
```