# Initialize a class with a tuple as input

Tags: python, python-3.x, class

I'm trying (because I think it should exists) to define a class but it would receive a tuple as an input.

What I mean is:

```
class Class_name:
    def __init__(self, (a,b)):
```

but it obviously generates an error. I don't know, just think I want to plot many complex numbers that I have written in a two-column list its real part and imaginary part. I know I can unpack, but I want to know if there is a way of doing it directly so i cant write (1,2) as an input, not 1,2. Thanks!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Expanding tuples into arguments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1993727/expanding-tuples-into-arguments)

Comment: Just use  `def __init__(self, a, b)` and then call `Class_name(*the_tuple_containing_a_and_b)`.

Comment: Python has a `complex` type for complex numbers. Consider the output of `list(map(complex, [1,2,3], [4,5,6]))`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have three options depending on what you're trying to accomplish exactly

#### One parameter

You can unpack in `__init__` if needed

```
class MyClass:
    def __init__(self, t):
        self.a, self.b = t

foo = (1, 2)
MyClass(foo)
```

#### Two parameters

You can unpack when instantiating if needed

```
class MyClass:
    def __init__(self, a, b):
        self.a = a
        self.b = b

foo = (1, 2)
MyClass(*foo)
```

#### Native `complex` type

```
class MyClass:
    def __init__(self, a):
        self.a = a

foo = 1+2j  # Equivalent to "complex(1, 2)"
MyClass(foo)
```