# Use not every argument of function in loop

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have got a function that has 2 arguments + 1 optional argument. I want to run that function in loop basing on lists with different length and don't know how to really do it. The function and loop would look like this:

```
def function(x,y,z=1):
   print(x,y,z)
```

```
LIST = [(1,1,1), (2,3,4), (5,6), (7,8), (9,9,9)]
for i in LIST:
   print(function(i[0], i[1], i[2]))
```

of course I could write smth like `if len(i) = 2: (...)`  in loop but I wonder if I can do it a better way.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Expanding tuples into arguments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1993727/expanding-tuples-into-arguments)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can expand the tuple and pass it as argument as Pawel has mention. *args will not be needed in this case.

```
def function(x,y,z=1):
   print(x,y,z)

LIST = [(1,1,1), (2,3,4), (5,6), (7,8), (9,9,9)]
for i in LIST:
   function(*i)
```

https://note.nkmk.me/en/python-argument-expand/

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way is to use `*args`:

```py
def function(x, y, z=1):
    print(x, y, z)

LIST = [(1,1,1), (2,3,4), (5,6), (7,8), (9,9,9)]
for i in LIST:
   function(*i)
```

Comment: You don't need to define the function as taking `*args` though, the original prototype works just fine.

Comment: Good point. `*i` will match positional arguments only