# How to pass a list of variables to a function as a "list" of arguments?

Tags: python, tuples, arguments

I am trying to build a function that sorts a list of dictionaries by one or more keys, having the list of keys passed to the function as variable (so, as a list of strings).

By following [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72899/how-do-i-sort-a-list-of-dictionaries-by-a-value-of-the-dictionary/69072597#69072597), I have arranged a few lines of code that sort a list of dictionaries by their keys:

```
import operator
newlist = sorted( list_to_be_sorted, key=operator.itemgetter('key1','key2') )
```

example:

```
list_to_be_sorted = [
                      {'name':'Homer', 'age':39, 'height':170}, 
                      {'name':'Milhouse', 'age':10, 'height':110}, 
                      {'name':'Bart', 'age':10, 'height':112} 
                    ]

newlist = sorted( list_to_be_sorted, key=operator.itemgetter('age','name') ) # My_line

print(newlist)
```

> [{'name': 'Bart', 'age': 10, 'height':112},
>   {'name': 'Milhouse', 'age': 10, 'height':110},
> {'name': 'Homer', 'age': 39, 'height':170}]

Now what I want to build is a function that calls the function defined at My_line and takes as inputs:

1. a `list_to_be_sorted`
2. a list of variables, in which each variable value will be passed as argument to `key=operator.itemgetter` in the function at My_line

so I want that function to be defined like this:

```
def order_list_of_dicts_by_keys( list_to_be_sorted, keys_list ):
    pass
```

where, in this case, `keys_list = ['age','name']`

So I have run into this problem, that is:

> How to pass a list of variables to a function as a
> "list" of arguments ?

This is what I tryed:

```
import operator

def order_list_of_dicts_by_keys(list_to_be_sorted, keys_strings):       
    items = tuple(keys_strings)
    sorted_list = sorted(list_to_be_sorted, key=operator.itemgetter( items )
    return sorted_list
```

How can I "strip" the items tuple of its parentheses, so that I can pass the correct expression to `key=operator.itemgetter` ?

Comment: Duplicate: [Expanding tuples into arguments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1993727/expanding-tuples-into-arguments)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SOLVED

It is impossible to "strip" a tuple of its parentheses, but it is possible to "unpack it" with the **unpacking operator** (`*`)

So the function becomes:

```
import operator

def order_list_of_dicts_by_keys(list_to_be_sorted, keys_list):
    items = tuple(keys_list)
    return sorted(list_to_be_sorted, key=operator.itemgetter(*items))
```

Comment: Do you mean *strip*?