# pyautoguy.pixel TypeError: pixel() missing 1 required positional argument: 'y'

Tags: python, pyautogui

```
import pyautogui

while True:
    mouse_position = pyautogui.position()
    print(mouse_position)
    if pyautogui.pixel(mouse_position)[0] == 255:
        pyautogui.mouseDown()
        pyautogui.mouseUp()
        print("Target detected!")
    else:
        print("Nothing detected!")`
```

I'm getting the mouse position (x, y) but when I put it in the parenthesis `pyautogui.pixel(mouse_position)` it gives me the error:

```
TypeError: pixel() missing 1 required positional argument: 'y'
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Expanding tuples into arguments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1993727/expanding-tuples-into-arguments)

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Answer (score 0):

Use `pyautogui.pixel(*mouse_position)` to unpack the tuple. Alternatively:

```py
x, y = pyautogui.position()
pyautogui.pixel(x, y)
```