# What is a Selenium locator in Python specifically?

Tags: python, selenium, expected-condition

My question comes from trying to understand the following code (which is meant to wait for a particular element to be loaded on the page before proceeding):

```py
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

# ... start chromium_driver 

wait_timeout = 10
wait = WebDriverWait(chromium_driver, wait_timeout)

target_id = "CookiePopup"
target_element = wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, target_id)))
```

I can understand what a locator is conceptually ("[a way to identify elements on a page](https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/webdriver/elements/locators/)"), but I'm trying to wrap my head around its structure and specification as an object in this context (namely, the signature of `EC.presence_of_element_located(locator)`). N.B., that the `(By.ID, target_id)` part in the code above **needs** to be enclosed in parenthesis; i.e.,

```py
EC.presence_of_element_located(By.ID, target_id)
```

causes

```py
TypeError: __init__() takes 2 positional arguments but 3 were given
```

The documentation explains that "[a locator] is the argument passed to the Finding element methods".

The [Finding element methods](https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/webdriver/elements/finders/) page shows that the `find_element()` method in Python **takes two arguments, which is the part that I find somewhat confusing**:

```py
vegetable = driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, "tomatoes")
```

In addition, `By.CLASS_NAME`, `By.ID` etc. are actually properties that contain strings ("class name" and "id" respectively).

Compare this to the Java (or any of the other languages) code:

```java
WebElement vegetable = driver.findElement(By.className("tomatoes"));
```

which makes more sense: `By.className()` is a method, which takes the (HTML) class name as an argument and returns a locator object that matches elements with that class name.

Given the above, would it be accurate to describe the *locator* as a *tuple* of two *str*, with the first string being the type of identifier used and the second string being the value of that identifier? And as a follow-up question, why is Python different in this way than the other languages?

Answer (score 0):

The documentation doesn't make it clear (to me anyway) why you have to pass the arguments enclosed in parenthesis, but have a look at the source code for that function here:

https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/py/_modules/selenium/webdriver/support/expected_conditions.html#presence_of_element_located

You can see that in the implementation of presence_of_element_located(), it takes whatever you pass as a locator and passes that argument on in a call to `find_element(*locator)`

Note that asterisk (*) is used in Python to unpack the contents of a tuple (or any iterable). For more info on that, see this answer:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/1993732

Comment: Thanks, but the source code doesn't really improve my understanding. I suppose it's consistent with everything I said about the locator being some sort of tuple (which, btw, explains why it needs to be passed enclosed in a parenthesis; without the parenthesis, it would be interpreted as two arguments, as opposed to a single argument of type tuple), but we're still lacking a clear definition for a locator and also an explanation as to why the choice was made to be implemented in such a bizarre way (in comparison to the other languages).