# Why am I getting error "module 'a.b' has no attribute 'position(1,2,3)'"

Tags: python-3.x

I've tried:

```
import a
from a import b
for i in range(1,10):
    c = position(i,2,3)
    maybe = getattr(b, str(c))
    position = geo[maybe]
```

After running this, I get the error in the title. But when I just write:

```
import a
from a import b
position = geo[b.position(1,2,3)]
```

I don't get an error. I've also tried using a function, but I get the same error:

```
def some_function(obj):
    for attribute in [c]:
        getattr(obj, str(attribute))
position = geo[some_function(b)]
```

How can I fix this so that I can use this variable as an attribute?

Comment: `getattr(b, 'position(1, 2, 3)')` != `getattr(b, 'position')(1, 2, 3)`

Comment: @0x5453 is 'b.position(1,2,3)' = 'getattr(b, 'position')(1, 2, 3)'?

Comment: @PranavHosangadi how can I get `getattr(b, position(1,2,3))` using c?

Comment: @Mat apologies, I misspoke. `b.position(1, 2, 3)` is the same as `getattr(b, 'position')(1, 2, 3)`. I don't know what your first code does, because I don't know what `position` or `c` is.  Please post a [mre]

Comment: @PranavHosangadi How can I use `getattr(b, 'position')(1,2,3)` with a variable as (1,2,3)? Whenever I try to use a variable instead of (1,2,3) I get the error:   `position.__init__(position, str)
did not match C++ signature:
    __init__(_object*, int, unsigned int, unsigned char)
    __init__(_object*, int, unsigned int)
    __init__(_object*)`

Comment: _"Whenever I try to use a variable instead of (1,2,3)"_: What is the code you tried that gave you this error?

Comment: @PranavHosangadi `for i in range(1,10):            q = (i,2,3)     maybe = getattr(b, 'position')(str(q))` If I remove `str` I get the same error except it says `position.__init__(position, tuple) did not match C++ signature: ...`

Comment: Well, your `b.position` method expects _three arguments_. You are passing it _one argument_ that is a string. Why not just do `maybe = getattr(b, 'position')(i, 2, 3)`? If you really want to use `q`, then [_unpack_ the tuple](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1993727/expanding-tuples-into-arguments) into the arguments of the function using `maybe = getattr(b, 'position')(*q)`

Answer (score 0):

You are not using the variable `c` in the correct way as @0x5453 said. use this instead:

```
import a
from a import b
for i in range(1,10):
    position = geo[b.position(i,2,3)]
```