# python add a list of variables as positional arguments for functions

Tags: python, django, function, arguments

I have a list of variables that need to be passed in a couple of functions that take the same number of arguments.

```
a = 1
b = 'hello'
c = 1.9

args = (a, b, c)

op = func_a(args) if <cond1> else func_b(args)

def func_a(a, b, c):
    ...
    
def func_b(a, b, c):
    ...
```

But sending this as a tuple, the tuple is set to arg `a` and the function expects args `b` and `c` as well.

How can I pass these tuple as `a`, `b`, and `c`respectively?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Expanding tuples into arguments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1993727/expanding-tuples-into-arguments)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `*` to unpack the tuple:

```
op = func_a(*args) if <cond1> else func_b(*args)
```

This will unpack the tuple and pass the parameters as separate arguments.